# C# entity framework for loop dynamic connection string

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, monitoring

I am a DBA and have decided as a project to help me learn c# / ef to build an app that monitors sql servers, the idea is to develop a windows service that runs to collect all the stats from various sql instances using scheduled jobs in .net quartz. i.e. connected users and details from various dynamic management views.

to store the configuration data i.e. what servers to monitor I am using an sql database so it just contains a table of servers to monitor you will be able to add move via a web ui.

now the issue I have is how to loop through the servers "table" in EF and obtain the connection strings column and use this to connect to the various sql instances to get stats. (these will later be written back to the database for analysis by a front end)

e.g.configuration table data:
servername: test server
connectionstring: testserver\inst1

hope that all makes sense, thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a list of all your connection string keys like this-

```
List<String> DataVaseKeys = new List<String>(); DataVaseKeys.Add("testserver\inst1");
 DataVaseKeys.Add("testserver\inst2");
  foreach (var key in DataVaseKeys)  {

    string currentConString=System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
        ConnectionStrings[key].ConnectionString;

    //access to the data base with your connection string here 
 }
```

Comment: ideally the list needs to be bound to the database table.

Comment: Like this? foreach (DataRow row in myDataTable.Rows)
{
  string currentConString= (row["ServerName"]);
}